# how to give null value to the database through ruby on rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `model` i have the following bit of code.

```
 hash_values = JSON.parse(question_hash)
 hash_values.each do |k,v|
   b = UpdateData.new
   b.question, b.answer, b.phase = v[0].to_i, v[1], v[2].to_i
   b.save!
 end
```

I have a problem of phase value. `b.phase` has an `id` of `0 to 5` and it also should be `null`. When the data is not entered for the phase the value  is `""(.to_i = 0)` it considered as `0` in database. I need to store an `null` value rather than `0` if phase value is `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
hash_values.each do |k,v|
  b = UpdateData.new
  b.question, b.answer = v[0].to_i, v[1]
  b.phase = v[2].blank? ? nil : v[2].to_i
  b.save!
end
```

Comment: hi... thanks... and one doubt... will you explain me why we using double question mark after blank? am very new to ruby on rails..

Comment: The method name is `blank?` so that is one question mark, the other is due to the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Ruby) (or 'inline if statement')

Comment: thats true @Veger, and unlike empty?, "".blank? and nil.blank? both will return true

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the string is empty:

```
if v[2].empty?
  b.phase = nil
else
  b.phase = v[2].to_i
end
```

or a nice one liner using a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Ruby):

```
p.phase = v[2].empty? ? nil : v[2].to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [gem](https://github.com/tilsammans/nilly_vanilly) that can do that for you automatically for every attributes existing in your model :

Add this to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` :

```
gem 'nilly_vanilly'
```

This gem will convert any empty string into a NIL value to be store into your DB.

====== UPDATE =====

I just tried this Gem and it is not working. I reported it, and the developper said there was an incompatibility with postgreSQL. He is patching the gem. In the time being, I end up with creating my own library.

Just create the file **lib/my_model_tools.rb** containing the following lines :

```
module MyModelTools
  private

    def blank_string_attributes_to_nil
      self.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
        self.send("#{attr_name}=", nil) if attr_value.kind_of?(String) && attr_value == ''
      end
    end
end
```

Then you have to add these lines **into each of your app/models/*** files :

```
require Rails.root.to_s + '/lib/my_model_tools.rb'

class MyExampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  include MyModelTools
  before_validation :blank_string_attributes_to_nil

  ...

end
```

This will convert any empty string attributes into a NIL value to be store into your DB (for the models where you copy the lines above).

So you won't have to assign each attribute by hand to NIL when they are empty string.